# Magento 2 Viva wallet Checkout (Exception): Unable to create order code does not support currency '978'

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.4, payment-gateway

Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to create order code (Person 691e86c8-c565-4aa4-beb8-329173fcf54b does not support currency '978')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viva wallet does not support currency '978' issue Magento 2 can be cause you have selected wrong currency type for your magento store.

On the Admin Panel, go Stores > Settings > Configuration.
On the left panel, under General, select Currency Setup.
Open the Currency Options section,
Choose the primary currency for the Base Currency in the online transaction.
Assign Default Display Currency to the currency that you use to display pricing in your store.
#Make sure we are using exactly similar currency type with viva wallet and magento store.

Thats all you need to do and it will work.

I've spent all day to find this issue hope the same works for  you all the best.